# How can I compare two dataframes row by row in pandas with insensitive cases?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data:

```
d = {'ID': [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 14], 'NAME': ['KWI', 'NED', 'RICK', 'NICH', 'DIONIC', 'RICHARD', 'ROCKY', 'CARLOS', 'SIDARTH'], 'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'COUNTRY':['MEXICO', 'ITALY', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND', 'GERMANY', 'UNITED STATES', 'JAPAN', 'SPAIN', 'BRAZIL'], 'ID_CITY':[10, 20, 21, 31, 18, 27, 36, 86, 28], 'CITY':['MX', 'IT', 'CA', 'ENG', 'GE', 'US', 'JP', 'SP', 'BZ'], 'STATUS': ['OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK', 'NOT', 'OK']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df:
      ID       NAME      ID_COUNTRY     COUNTRY        ID_CITY     CITY     STATUS
0     14       KWI           1           MEXICO           10         MX        OK
1     14       NED           2           ITALY            20         IT        OK
2     14       RICK          3           CANADA           21         CA        OK
3     14       NICH          4           ENGLAND          31         ENG       OK
4     14       DIONIC        5           GERMANY          18         GE        OK 
5     14       RICHARD       6           UNITED STATES    27         US        NOT
6     14       ROCKY         7           JAPAN            36         JP        OK
7     15       CARLOS        8           SPAIN            86         SP        NOT
8     15       SIDHART       9           BRAZIL           28         BZ        OK
```

The `df` is the base data. The data that I need to compare with `df` is `df1`:

```
d1 = {'ID': [14, 10, 14, 11, 14], 'NAME': ['Kwi', 'NED', 'riCK', 'nich', 'DIONIC'], 'ID_COUNTRY':[1, 2, 3, 6, 5], 'COUNTRY':['MXICO', 'itaLY', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND', 'GERMANY'], 'ID_CITY':[10, 22, 21, 31, 18], 'CITY':['MX', 'AT', 'CA', 'ENG', 'EG'], 'STATUS': ['', 'OK', '', 'OK', '']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

df1:
      ID       NAME    ID_COUNTRY    COUNTRY      ID_CITY    CITY     STATUS
0     14       Kwi          1         MXICO           10       MX        
1     10       NED          2         itaLY           22       AT        OK
2     14       riCK         3         CANADA          21       CA
3     11       nich         6         ENGLAND         31       ENG       OK
4     14       DIONIC       5         GERMANY         18       EG
```

Desired output 1 (The values that not match must appear highlighted):

```
 The data in df1 that not match with df is:
      ID       NAME    ID_COUNTRY    COUNTRY      ID_CITY    CITY     STATUS
0     14       Kwi          1         *MXICO*         10       MX        **
1    *10*      NED          2          itaLY         *22*      AT        OK
2     14       riCK         3          CANADA         21       CA        **
3    *11*      nich         6          ENGLAND        31       ENG       OK
4     14       DIONIC       5          GERMANY        18       *EG*      **
                          *TWO ROWS ARE MISSING*
```

Note: In this output is necessary that the comparisons row by row will be insensitive to strings as itaLY, Kwi, riCK, nich that values are ok because are the same.

Desired output 2:

```
 The data in df1 that not match with df is in :
 COUNTRY, STATUS with ID 14, NAME Kwi, ID_COUNTRY 1.
 ID, ID_CITY, CITY with ID 10, NAME NED, ID_COUNTRY 2.
 STATUS with ID 14, NAME riCK, ID_COUNTRY 3.
 ID, ID_COUNTRY with ID 11, NAME nich, ID_COUNTRY 6.
 CITY, STATUS with ID 14, NAME DIONIC, ID_COUNTRY 5.
 TWO ROWS ARE MISSING.
```

The result it just need to be a comparison of the data that match the length of `df1`, but also there is the possibility that rows mismatch following the `ID` from `df` as I show here (14) the values 15 in ID are no considered. I think the second output is more specific and efficient and first one it will be slow to visualize if there are many data to compare.

I hope everyone understand what is the point of this issue and found and answer. I have been struggling with this some time and did not get the solution I want, that's why I came here with you guys. Thanks for read and hope contribute to this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one wants a case insensitive comparison between strings in python, one would like to set both strings to upper or lower case and then do a traditional `==` or `!=` comparison.

When using pandas, this can be achieved by the `.str` Series method, which allows the use of string methods such as `.upper()` and `.lower()`. In your case, a possible solution would be:

```
df, df1 = df.astype(str), df1.astype(str)
_df = df1.copy()

for i in df1.index:
    comparison = df.loc[i].str.upper() != df1.loc[i].str.upper()
    _df.loc[i, comparison] = '*' + df1.loc[i, comparison].astype(str) + '*'
```

If we print the resulting dataframe `_df` we get your desired output 1:

```
     ID    NAME ID_COUNTRY  COUNTRY ID_CITY  CITY STATUS
0    14     Kwi          1  *MXICO*      10    MX     **
1  *10*     NED          2    itaLY    *22*  *AT*     OK
2    14    riCK          3   CANADA      21    CA     **
3  *11*    nich        *6*  ENGLAND      31   ENG     OK
4    14  DIONIC          5  GERMANY      18  *EG*     **
```

In this case I'm assuming that corresponding rows have the same index across both dataframes.

For your second desired output, you can just iterate over each row again:

```
print("Data in df1 that does't match df:")
for i in _df.index:
    not_matching_cols = _df.loc[i].str.endswith('*')
    if not_matching_cols.any():
        print(','.join(_df.loc[i, not_matching_cols].index), end=' ')
        print('with', 'NAME', df1.loc[i, 'NAME'], 'ID_COUNTRY', df1.loc[i, 'ID_COUNTRY'])
```

If you also want to print the numbers of rows missing on `df1` you can just add

```
print(df.shape[0] - df1.shape[0], 'ROWS ARE MISSING')
```

The output of this last part should be:

```
Data in df1 that does't match df:
COUNTRY,STATUS with NAME Kwi ID_COUNTRY 1
ID,ID_CITY,CITY with NAME NED ID_COUNTRY 2
STATUS with NAME riCK ID_COUNTRY 3
ID,ID_COUNTRY with NAME nich ID_COUNTRY 6
CITY,STATUS with NAME DIONIC ID_COUNTRY 5
4 ROWS ARE MISSING
```

Comment: Hi @Ralubrusto. How can I get the print in a function?

Comment: If you want a function to do this kind of print, you can just copy this entire code inside a function with two input arguments like `def my_function(df, df1):`. THis way it will do this printing for any dataframes `df` and `df1` that you provide

Comment: But I think I will need to do a list and append the strings to get the output in the return if this happens or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you have been using to compare it row by row or what your conditions are, but one thing you can try is converting all the string rows to lowercase strings...

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes('object').applymap(str.lower))
# 'object' is used to refer to strings in pandas dtypes
```

Or if you want to preserve the original columns, you could try making new, temporary columns...

```
df['name_lower'] = df['name'].apply(str.lower)
df1['name_lower'] = df1['name'].apply(str.lower)
```

Comment: Yes. Indeed I was trying to use somethig like: `df1[['NAME','COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'STATUS']].apply(lambda col: col.str.lower().isin(df[['NAME','COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'STATUS']]))` to get all at once but give me false for all the rows and when I do this individually give `True` for the `nan` instead of `False`

Comment: didn't realize there were nan's in your data. Try setting doing df = df.fillna(''), so that the dtype is a string. Otherwise, lmk if this method is still not helping solve your issue